# Member function template doesn't compile on clang, but does on GCC

Tags: c++, clang

In the code below I have a class template named `zipcode`, which has a member function template named `get_postbox`. It compiles in GCC but not in clang 3.9. Why doesn't clang accept this code?

In clang I get this error:

```
<source>:34:41: error: expected expression
return my_postoffice.get_postbox<K>();
^
```

Furthermore, calling the same code (same as `zipcode::get_postbox`) from a **non-member** function template named `non_member_function_template()` does not cause the error!

To see it for yourself and play with it, here's the code in Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/g/MpYzGP

---

Here's the code:

```cpp
template <int K>
struct postbox
{
    int val() const 
    {
      return K;
    }
};

template <int A, int B, int C>
struct postoffice
{
  postbox<A> _a;

  template<int I>
  postbox<I> get_postbox()
  {
    switch( I )
    {
      case A: return _a;
    }
  }
};

template <typename PO>
struct zipcode
{
  PO my_postoffice;

  template<int K>
  postbox<K> get_postbox()
  {
    // The error is on this line
    return my_postoffice.get_postbox<K>();
  }
};

// Here's a function template that isn't a member, and it compiles.
template<int D>
int non_member_function_template()
{
  postoffice<123,345,678> po;
  auto box = po.get_postbox<D>();
  return box.val(); 
}

int test_main()
{
  return non_member_function_template<123>();
}
```

Comment: You need `return my_postoffice.template get_postbox<K>();`.

Comment: @songyuanyao Nice! That worked. Thank you!

Comment: See more details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the template keyword when using template member functions like this:

```
my_postoffice.template get_postbox<K>()
```

and

```
po.template get_postbox<D>()
```

c.f. here: http://ideone.com/W0owY1 for the code 
and here: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for the exact explanation when to use the template keyword